# How do I move or migrate RabbitMQ Server config and database files to a different directory

Tags: windows-10, rabbitmq

I inherited a RabbitMQ Server installed on a Windows 10 Workstation. The config, database, logs etc. are in the user's folder that installed RabbitMQ initially. I need to move or migrate these to a public directory like `C:\ProgramData\RabbitMQ Server\`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I managed to do it based on [this](https://www.rpic.com/knowledgebase/imagenow/changing-rabbitmq_base-directory-windows-installation/) article:

1. Completely uninstalled erlang and RabbitMQ.
2. Installed erlang as Admin user.
3. Installed RabbitMQ but unchecked 'RabbitMQ Service'.
4. Opened RabbitMQ Command Prompt
5. Typed 'set RABBITMQ_BASE="C:\ProgramData\RabbitMQ Server"'
6. Then typed 'rabbitmq-service install'
7. 'net start RabbitMQ'
8. 'net stop RabbitMQ'
9. Deleted all in 'C:\ProgramData\RabbitMQ Server' directory
10. Copied all from previous user's directory into
    'C:\ProgramData\RabbitMQ Server'
11. 'net start RabbitMQ'